# Positivity of Bulk modulus and shear modulus in isotropic materials

Tags: thermodynamics, elasticity, moduli

I have been searching through many resources, but could not find a proper thermodynamic reasoning for why bulk and shear moduli for isotropic materials should be positive. Some resources like [eFunda](http://www.efunda.com/formulae/solid_mechanics/mat_mechanics/elastic_constants_g_k.cfm)
or [this TTU lecture](http://www.phys.ttu.edu/~cmyles/Phys4309-5304/Lectures/Lecture4f%20Elastic3.ppt) 
state something like

> *Second Law of Thermodynamics and understanding that a positive shear stress leads to a positive shear strain implies ...*

However I did not find proper thermodynamic reasoning behind that. My supervisor even thinks that there is no underlying thermodynamics behind that setting these moduli to be positive.

Can you help me?

Comment: Wouldn't a negative bulk modulus mean the more you tried to compress the body the more it expanded?

Comment: Yes but what is the thermodynamic reasoning that it may not happen.